# How can I change the language in wikihow API using python

Tags: python, api

**How can I change the language in wikihow API using python**

`pip install pywikihow`

```
from pywikihow import WikiHow, search_wikihow


max_results = 1  # default for optional argument is 10
how_tos = search_wikihow("how to learn programming", max_results)
assert len(how_tos) == 1
how_tos[0].print()


# for efficiency and to get unlimited entries, the best is to use the generator

for how_to in WikiHow.search("how to learn python"):
    how_to.print()
```

But the API searches in English only, even if I type the search title in a different language

[*Note that wikihow provides other languages for searching ...*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpoV9.png)

**So how do I change the language in wikihow API using python Code ...**

I tried to put this code :

```
how_tos = search_wikihow("how to learn programming", max_results, lang='ar')
```

It worked, but not optimally For example, I tried using the Arabic language, but before the result appeared, it write incomprehensible codes such as% D8% B5% D9% 86% D8% B9% D8% B9% D8% B5 % D9% 8A% D8% B1% D8% A7% D9% 84% D8% A3% D9% 86% D8% A7% D9% 86% D8% A7%

[As shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTdjz.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/OpenJarbas/PyWikiHow/) a `lang` can be passed to `search_wikihow()`

```
def search_wikihow(query, max_results=10, lang="en"):
    return list(WikiHow.search(query, max_results, lang))
```

And the available languages are

```
lang2url = {
        "en": "http://www.wikihow.com/",
        "es": "http://es.wikihow.com/",
        "pt": "http://pt.wikihow.com/",
        "it": "http://www.wikihow.it/",
        "fr": "http://fr.wikihow.com/",
        "ru": "http://ru.wikihow.com/",
        "de": "http://de.wikihow.com/",
        "zh": "http://zh.wikihow.com/",
        "nl": "http://nl.wikihow.com/",
        "cz": "http://www.wikihow.cz/",
        "id": "http://id.wikihow.com/",
        "jp": "http://www.wikihow.jp/",
        "hi": "http://hi.wikihow.com/",
        "th": "http://th.wikihow.com/",
        "ar": "http://ar.wikihow.com/",
        "ko": "http://ko.wikihow.com/",
        "tr": "http://www.wikihow.com.tr/",
        "vn": "http://www.wikihow.vn/",
    }
```

So you can try:

```
how_tos = search_wikihow("how to learn programming", max_results, lang='es')
```

---

**Additional Info**

The reason you see the `D8% B5% D9% 86% D8% B9% D8% B9%` text is because this is how a URI parses arabic language to be readable by the web server.

When you call `how_tos[0].print()` it makes a call to print the title, which is why you see this when calling the command.

```
def print(self, extended=False):
        if not extended:
            print(self.summary)
        else:
            print(self.title)
            print(self.intro)
            for s in self.steps:
                s.print(extended)
```

If you need to keep the title, we can use `urllib` to "unquote" the `url` and apply that value to the classes `_title` variable.

```
from urllib import unquote

how_tos[0]._title = unquote(how_tos[0].title)

how_tos[0].title
#'البرمجة'

how_tos[0].print()
#البرمجة
#1 - لا تشغل بالك كثيرًا باختيار اللغة التي تبدأ بتعلمها.
```

---

**Translation**

With your example you sent an english string to an arabic search, which seems to be returning less then optimal results. We can translate your text prior to sending to ensure our search is relevant.

`pip install translate`

**Code**

```
from pywikihow import WikiHow, search_wikihow
from translate import Translator

## Translate English to Arabic ##
translator= Translator(to_lang="ar")
translation = translator.translate("how to learn programming")

how_tos = search_wikihow(translation, max_results, lang='ar')

how_tos[0].print()
```

**Output**

```
%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A9
1 - لا تشغل بالك كثيرًا باختيار اللغة التي تبدأ بتعلمها.
2 - ابحث عبر الإنترنت عن أحد المصادر التعليمية للغة التي ترغب في تعلمها.
3 - حمل برنامج تحرير نصي جيد للبرمجة.
4 - حمل مترجم الأكواد اللازم.
5 - ابدأ مشروعك الأول.
6 - استفد من خاصية التعليق على الكود.
7 - اطلع على كيفية برمجة البرامج والمواقع الإلكترونية الأخرى.
8 - احضر الدروس التعليمية.
9 - اعمل على توسيع معارفك وخبراتك.
10 - تعلم المزيد من اللغات.
11 - تحلَ بالصبر.
12 - تعلم كيفية العمل مع الآخرين في بيئة عمل تعاونية.
13 - احصل على وظيفة تتيح لك التمرن على مهاراتك في البرمجة.
14 - تواصل مع غيرك من المبرمجين.
15 - تدرب وتدرب وتدرب.
```

It may also be more suitable to pass `extended=True` to the `print()` function to return the majority of the result you're seeking.

`how_tos[0].print(extended=True)`

Comment: **It worked, but not optimally** For example, I tried using the Arabic language, but before the result appeared, it used to write incomprehensible codes such as% D8% B5% D9% 86% D8% B9% D8% B9% D8% B5% D9% 8A% D8% B1% D8% A7% D9% 84% D8% A3% D9% 86% D8% A7% D9% 86% D8% A7% D8% B3

Comment: Could you please provide some examples

Comment: Thanks, I attached an explanation in the text of the question you can now watch it

Comment: @AhmadSadekAlbasatneh I have updated the answer covering this and more.